# How to reload the data in an ember-light-table from the database without a page refresh

Tags: ember.js

Currently I have an ember-light table which is connected to a model from a django database. New things are pushed into this database all the time and I need my table to be up to date.

At the moment I refresh the page every minute which fetches from the database if the cache is old (using store.query). However, this causes the page to reload everything and the page goes blank for a while.

Is it possible to reload the data from the django db and update the table and have the table stay on screen the whole time?

Route:

```
  actions: {
  refresh: function () {
    this.refresh();
  }
},
```

Component:

```
   let currentTable = new Table(this.get('columns'),this.get('current'), {enableSync: true});
```

Comment: By page refresh you are referring to executing the model hook again, aren't you? Got confused by that term cause by page refresh I thought you mean reloading the full application (similar to F5).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I don't refresh the entire page. The refresh that I was referring to is in the code snippet above which I believe executes the model hook.

Comment: I guess you have to options: a) use `findAll()` to get a live view into the store, add a client-side filter to mimic your backend query, fetch additional data into the store; b) manually constructing a result array, which supports pushing additional data to it. Don't have time to elaborate right now. But maybe it's enough as a starter?

Comment: Can you share your code where the Table is built? It looks like there are some options for updating the data in place at http://offirgolan.github.io/ember-light-table/docs/classes/Table.html, but it would be helpful to see how you're building the table to answer this questions.

Comment: Hi, I added how I create my table which is inside the init of my component.